# Redirect folder on one HDD to a folder on another HDD

Tags: windows, file-management, folder-redirection

This may be a simple question but I couldn't find any answers - folder redirection usually refers to redirecting profile folders only.

I have two hard drives in my laptop: `C:` (an SSD) and `D:` (a regular hard drive). I'd like to keep some files on `C:` but transparently access those files through the `D:` drive. For example, I'd like to have:

- `C:\Source` - this is where I want my physical files to be stored.
- `D:\X_Drive` - this folder is mapped to a virtual `X:` drive, using `subst X: D:\X_Drive`.
- `X:\Source` - when I go into this folder, I'd to see the contents of `C:\Source`.

Effectively, I'm looking for a way to map `D:\X_Drive` to `C:\Source`. How can I do this? I have Windows 7 Ultimate.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Junctions (also called symbolic links or reparse points) allows you to do that. You can use mklink in the command prompt (with /D for directory) to create them:

```
mklink /D C:\Source D:\Source
```

This will be transparent to applications - that is they will see it as a regular folder.

In Windows Vista/7, it is safe to delete C:\Source from Windows Explorer, or from the command prompt (del C:\Source) as it will only delete the link, without affecting the content of your target folder (D:\Source). However, in WinXP/2000 it would also delete the target content, so you should use rmdir, or the Sysinternal [Junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768) utility in this case.

Comment: For the asker, there is also a Wikipedia article you should check out when it comes directory deleting with junctions, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point#Observed_effects)

Comment: @The_aLiEn Thanks, I wasn't sure if rmdir was safe in XP, and apparently it is.

Comment: To be clear, the mklink syntax for creating a new symbolic directory linked to an existing target, it's `mklink /D (new path) (target path) like mklink /D C:\users\chris\.ssh C:\users\chris\dropbox\.ssh`

Answer (score -1):

There is a Simpler way to install it onto a Dif drive and let windows think its where Oculus installed it Called MKLink

First Go to where ever you want to install I will use the dir path I am using

D:\Games and create your folder Oculus

search for CMD and run as administrator

type in 
mklink /j "C:\Program Files\Oculus" "D:\Games\Oculus"

now when you go to C:\Program Files\ You should see a folder that looks like a shortcut. Windows will treat it like a actual Folder and not a short cut (making a short cut with the windows Drag and Drop method will not work and if you install it using that method windows will just install it on the C Drive any ways"

You can also make a batch file and put it in your Oculus folder so if you ever need to reinstall windows or what ever you can simply run that batch file real quick and reinstall a tad faster with out having to look up how.